# Oracle 11g _ ORA-00904 error message with Insert statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created a simple table:

```
 CREATE TABLE "ADVUPGRD"."GL_CAMPUSEMAILS" 
 ("Campus" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), "SEND_TO" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR), "SEND_CC"    
   VARCHAR2(250 CHAR), "SEND_BCC" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR))
```

The table got created, I can do select * from gl_campusemails and it gets me a blank row since I have not populated this table yet.
When I'm populating the table I'm using this:

```
INSERT INTO GL_CAMPUSEMAILS (Campus, Send_To, Send_CC, Send_BCC)
VALUES('CP', 'as@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com', 'test2@gmail.com');
```

but I got this error message:

> Error starting at line : 8 in command -
>   INSERT INTO GL_CAMPUSEMAILS (Campus, Send_To, Send_CC, Send_BCC)
>      VALUES('CP', 'as@gmail.com', 'test@yahoo.com', 'test2@gmail.com')
>   Error at Command Line : 8 Column : 56
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SEND_BCC": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

I googled and found a lot of posting but they're mostly related to the use of reserved words in the select statement. 
I don't think the columns I used in here belong to any reserved words.What did I do wrong in here

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223 in a nutshell: Never use double quotes in SQL

Comment: Don't know, if this refers to your problem, but in your insert statement the double quotes are missing. Without double quotes all column names and table names are interpreted as upper case. But in your table columns are mixed case (because of the double quotes there). So it tries to insert into a column CAMPUS, but there is only a column named Campus - which is not the same ...

Answer (score 1):

If you use double quotes while creating the table, the column names are created exactly as you typed, case sensitive; thus, you insert should be:

```
INSERT INTO GL_CAMPUSEMAILS(
                            "Campus",
                            "SEND_TO",
                            "SEND_CC",
                            "SEND_BCC"
                           )
     VALUES (
             'CP',
             'as@gmail.com',
             'test@yahoo.com',
             'test2@gmail.com'
            );
```

If you create the table with no quotes, this will work fine

```
CREATE TABLE GL_CAMPUSEMAILS
(
    Campus                                  VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),
    SEND_TO                                 VARCHAR2(60 CHAR),
    SEND_CC                                 VARCHAR2(250 CHAR),
    SEND_BCC                                VARCHAR2(60 CHAR)
);

INSERT INTO GL_CAMPUSEMAILS(
                            Campus,
                            SEND_TO,
                            SEND_CC,
                            SEND_BCC
                           )
     VALUES (
             'CP',
             'as@gmail.com',
             'test@yahoo.com',
             'test2@gmail.com'
            );
```

Notice that not using double quotes, Oracle will consider all the objects with upper case names; so, for example, `"CAMPUS"`, `campus`, `CaMpUs` will work, while `"campus"` will not

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you! How come I did not get this kind of explanation when I googled for an answer. Thank you again, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: I modified it without double quotes to make it easier. Thanks guys!

Comment: @user1557856: read the manual ;) It's all explained there: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223